# Post-Loadtime Java ByteCode Injection

Tags: java, methods, hook, code-injection, bytecode

I am trying to hook methods of other classes in a Java program, I know this can be done with Java Agents at loadtime. But is there a way to do it once the .class file is loaded into the JVM, similar to dll hooking in c++ with Read/Writeprocessmemory()? Thank you.

Comment: See this post: http://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/practical-introduction-into-code-injection-with-aspectj-javassist-and-java-proxy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean method interception, there are two options

1) java.lang.reflect.Proxy. Below test makes a proxy for a list and intercepts its methods calls. Note that it works only with interfaces.

```
class Handler implements java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler {
    Object target;

    Handler(Object target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Before " + method.getName());
        Object res = method.invoke(target, args);
        System.out.println("After " + method.getName());
        return res;
    }
}
List list = new ArrayList();
List proxy = (List) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Test.class.getClassLoader(),
        new Class[] { List.class }, new Handler(list));
proxy.add(1);
```

prints

```
Before add
After add
```

2) Aspect-Oriented Programming. The easiest way to start using it, in my view, is Spring http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html